# Max Memory for Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I'm planning on buying a new Macbook this fall. I fail to order more than 16GB RAM for any mobile device, but I remember that previously, with smaller memory limits, some machines would inofficially also with more than just the 8GB.

Is there any way to make any of the current/new devices work with more than 16GB memory? Are there rumors of a new Macbook specification that will allow for more RAM?

*I know that this question has been asked previously , but I figure this is not a duplicate, as the boundary of technology and hardware is moving rapidly.**

Comment: Are you talking about a non retina Macbook Pro ?

Comment: Anything is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since retina Macbook Pro have their memory soldered to the mainboard I won't be possible to have more memory than sold by Apple.

About the last non retina MacBook Pro (mid-2012). [It's 16GB](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html)